# jQuery imgAreaSelect set initial selection with aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and the imgAreaSelect plugin. I am using the area select plugin so that users can crop their images to 16:9 aspect ratio before they upload.

I want to display an initial crop selection so that when they select the file, a thumbnail loads and the biggest possible 16:9 selection is selected with imgAreaSelect. I have the thumbnail loading etc but just cant get the aspect ratio part. This is what I have so far:

```
    // adds an image area select instance
    function addImgAreaSelect( img ){
            img.addClass( 'imgAreaSelect' ).imgAreaSelect({
                    handles : true,
                    aspectRatio : '16:9',
                    fadeSpeed : 1,
                    show : true
            });
            img.load(function(){ // set initial crop at 16:9 aspect ratio, calculate coordinates
                    // @todo
                    $( this ).imgAreaSelect({ x1 : 0, y1 : 0, x2 : this.width, y2 : this.height });

   });
}
```

Any help with this is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You are calling imgAraSelect 2 times? I don't understand

Comment: @MiguelStevens see the solution below. The second call to imgAreaSelect updates it with new values (the crop selection in this case). It doesn't re-init the whole plugin, just updates the values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this works for me:

```
// adds an image area select instance
function addImgAreaSelect( img ){
        img.addClass( 'imgAreaSelect' ).imgAreaSelect({
                handles : true,
                aspectRatio : '16:9',
                fadeSpeed : 1,
                show : true
        });
        img.load(function(){ // display initial image selection 16:9
                    var height = ( this.width / 16 ) * 9;
                    if( height <= this.height ){     
                            var diff = ( this.height - height ) / 2;
                            var coords = { x1 : 0, y1 : diff, x2 : this.width, y2 : height + diff };
                    }   
                    else{ // if new height out of bounds, scale width instead
                            var width = ( this.height / 9 ) * 16; 
                            var diff = ( this.width - width ) / 2;
                            var coords = { x1 : diff, y1 : 0, x2 : width + diff, y2: this.height };
                    }   
                $( this ).imgAreaSelect( coords );
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke the initial crop selection by adding below code

```
$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({  x1 : 0, y1 : 0, x2 : 180, y2: 180, aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true  , onSelectChange: preview });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addImgAreaSelect( img ){
        img.addClass( 'imgAreaSelect' ).imgAreaSelect({
                handles : true,
                aspectRatio : '16:9',
                fadeSpeed : 1,
                show : true
        });
        img.load(function(){
                var ratio = 19/9;
                var originalH = originalImg.height;
                var originalW = originalImg.width;
                var size =  Math.min(thumb.width()/ratio, thumb.height());
                var xBiggerThanY = thumb.width()/ratio > thumb.height();
                var fullSize = Math.max(thumb.width()/ratio, thumb.height());
                var sizeX1 = xBiggerThanY ? (fullSize - size) * ratio / 2 : 0;
                var sizeX2 = xBiggerThanY ? size*ratio-1 + (fullSize - size) * ratio / 2 : size*ratio-1;
                var sizeY1 = xBiggerThanY ? 0 : (fullSize - size) / 2;
                var sizeY2 = xBiggerThanY ? size - 1 : size - 1 + (fullSize - size) / 2;

                var initSelection = {x1: sizeX1, y1: sizeY1, x2: sizeX2, y2: sizeY2};
                $( this ).imgAreaSelect( initSelection );
        });
}
```